# Magento admin will not load when there is another action running

Tags: magento, admin

I do have my own Controller in Magento, that has been done by following the guidelines here:
http://alanstorm.com/magento_admin_controllers

My controller extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action and inside there is a method:

```
public function myAction() {
    sleep(1000);
    die('I am done');
}
```

When this method is running I cannot load any other Magento Admin pages. They will load eventually right after the method above is complete.
Also Frontend works fine, running the very same action from the Frontend controller does not cause Magento to hang like this.

Any solutions to keep my method in Admin and while this method is running, rest of the admin should stay usable?
Longest time this process runs is about 4-5 hours and it imports products. Yes I do have cron also set up, but I would like to give the user the ability to init processes at will also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have to answer this myself:

Solution is mega simple:

call this right before the long process (make sure that you have done manipulating the session data before calling this method, otherwise errors may occur)

```
session_write_close();
```

And voila, you can run multiple processes at the same time!

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature.

The workaround is to use two browsers, e.g. Firefox + Chrome, Firefox + Opera and so on.

It is better to work two-browser on these tasks as you don't want a crash in your other tabs to interrupt your import.

I know that is not an in-depth programming answer, sometimes the lateral solution works though.

Comment: Yes from another browser it works, but what part of the code is checking it? I am calling the method by fsockopen and passing the adminhtml cookie to it. I tried to pass some other user agent string, but it does not seem to solve the problem. Does anyone know at which part of the code this "browser check" is done?

Comment: You can have cron call your controller, running cron every two minutes is what I have, I also put in an admin grid and have it update the pricelist entries from 'new' to 'processing' to 'aborted' or 'processed' depending on how it works out. In that way the user can check on their updates.

Comment: Maybe I can call some function to trick Magento into thinking that the long method has been already dispatched? Is there any such method?